# Modifing comment into Spark table on Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to modify the comment associated to a table Spark,something like:

```
ALTER TABLE table CHANGE column1 column1 VARCHAR COMMENT "some comment"
```

But for the comment table description.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table IS 'This is a comment';
```

In Databricks:

```
spark.sql("COMMENT ON TABLE my_table IS 'This is a comment')
```

In pyspark:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.sql("COMMENT ON TABLE my_table IS 'This is a comment')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to update an existing comment for a column unless updating it in the COLUMNS_V2 table in metastore. The hack for this is to do

```
ALTER TABLE table CHANGE column1 column1 VARCHAR COMMENT "temp comment"
```

then

```
ALTER TABLE table CHANGE column1 column1 VARCHAR COMMENT "final intended comment"
```

Comment: Hey! What i want is change the COMMENT TABLE itself, not the COMMENT COLUMN of a table, is it possible?